# Failed to resolve module specifier "vue" ERROR on production

Tags: vue.js, nginx, vite

I'm trying to deploy my vue.js application on a digitalocean server. I've created the vue app with npm create vue@latest command. It runs with no errors locally, even when I run npm run build and then npm run preview, there's no errors, the app runs perfectly. When I hosted it on the server however, I get this error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "vue".
Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

On the server, This is the steps that I took :
in the project directory, ran

1. curl https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo bash
2. sudo apt install nodejs
3. npm install
4. npm run build

Did I miss anything? I've been looking for hours to find a problem but can't find any answers.
This is the package.json file :

```
{
  "name": "front",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .vue,.js,.jsx,.cjs,.mjs --fix --ignore-path .gitignore",
    "format": "prettier --write src/"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@vee-validate/i18n": "^4.12.6",
    "@vee-validate/rules": "^4.12.6",
    "axios": "^1.6.8",
    "vee-validate": "^4.12.6",
    "vue": "^3.4.21",
    "vue-router": "^4.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rushstack/eslint-patch": "^1.3.3",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^5.0.4",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^8.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.18",
    "eslint": "^8.49.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.17.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.37",
    "prettier": "^3.0.3",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "vite": "^5.1.6"
  }
}
```

This is the nginx config /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/digitalocean:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /var/www;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
                # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #       deny all;
        #}
}
```

/var/www/front is the path of my directory.
I'd appreciate any help!